# Mapping a column with no unique identifier in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes and I want to map a column from `df2` to `df1`, but I don't have one unique column to use as an index so I do the following:

```
df1['completion_time']=df1[['participant','Movement_type']].merge(df2,how='left').completion_time
```

but the end result doesn't match with the original dataframe, somethings is wrong

`df1`

```
participant  vis  total_time  Movement_type  
1194          8      24.747      A       
1194          4      22.151      B       
1190          8      28.853      A           
1190          4     137.254      B     
1197          8      21.244      A
```

`df2`

```
participant   question   completion_time   Movement_type
1194            40        11.0              A
1194            34        0.0               C       
1194            52        45.0              B
1190            52        30.0              B
1190            40        20.0              A
1197            34        0.0               C
```

and I am aiming to achieve this: `df3`

```
participant  vis  total_time  Movement_type  completion_time
1194          8      24.747      A          11.0            
1194          4      22.151      B           45.0
1190          8      28.853      A           20.0
1190          4     137.254      B          30.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2)`. This results in the correct df3 for me:

```
    participant vis total_time  Movement_type   question    completion_time
0   1194    8   24.747  A   40  11.0
1   1194    4   22.151  B   52  45.0
2   1190    8   28.853  A   40  20.0
3   1190    4   137.254 B   52  30.0
```

If you want to get rid of the unnecessary column, then just merge a subset of df2 where you keep the columns you want and the columns on which you merge.

`pd.merge(df1, df2.drop(columns='question'))`

```
    participant vis total_time  Movement_type   completion_time
0   1194    8   24.747  A   11.0
1   1194    4   22.151  B   45.0
2   1190    8   28.853  A   20.0
3   1190    4   137.254 B   30.0
```

Comment: I get an empty dataframe, I think we need to specify the index if we want to merge, right?

Comment: Check your code for errors. Which version of pandas are you using?

Comment: my current pandas version: 1.3.0